# Pass variable from request_uri to destination url

Tags: .htaccess, variables, request-uri

I need to create an htaccess rule that pass variable, if exists, from request_uri to destination url.

So, if request url contains "test=something" it should adds it to the new url if it doesn't already contains "test" var.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, if request_uri is "index.php?post=1&test=something&r=1" and incoming url is "index.php?post=3&r=4" (don't contains 'test' variable), I need to append "test=something" to this url. How can I do that?

Comment: Ok, I think I can't explain as well... I try again. So, image that you are visiting the page "index.php?post=1&test=something&r=1". Now, you click a button and the page redirect you to "index.php?post=3&r=4". Well, now the new page doesn't have the "test" var... I need to append the previous "test=something". Where "something" should be any text.

Comment: In that case nothing! I want to append "test" var only if request_uri contains it!

Comment: Uhm, ok... my fault! Sorry. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)test=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /index\.php\?(?:.+?&)?(test=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,QSA,NC,R=302]
```

However do keep in mind that `HTTP_REFERER` can be spoofed by clients.

Comment: uhm... it doesn't works! I've noticed that my .htaccess already has following lines:
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)post=abc(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)cat=xxx(&|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin.*
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.come/?cat=xxx[QSA,L]`
How can I modify it to add also your code?

Comment: I've updated the rule. Keep it just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: **it doesn't work** is never a useful comment. It doesn't give any information of your context and problem.

Comment: You're right. Ok. Give me some time to write a better description, ok? Thanks